# Python Dataframe simple average error: TypeError: Expected tuple, got str

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, typeerror

I'm executing a very simple operation where I want to change a value in a dataframe to be the average of the preceding values.

```
period = 14    
u[u.index[period-1]] = np.mean( u[:period] )
```

However this returns a lengthy error ending with

```
File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2399, in pandas._libs.lib.tuples_to_object_array

TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
```

I am very much a novice..

thank you very much in advance.

[edit]

Data sample:

```
Instrument  S&PCOMP
Field   
Dates   
12/05/2015  0
13/05/2015  0
14/05/2015  22.62
15/05/2015  1.63
18/05/2015  6.47
19/05/2015  0
20/05/2015  0
21/05/2015  4.97
22/05/2015  0
25/05/2015  0
26/05/2015  0
27/05/2015  19.28
28/05/2015  0
```

Expected output:

```
Instrument  S&PCOMP
Field   
Dates   
12/05/2015  0
13/05/2015  0
14/05/2015  22.62
15/05/2015  1.63
18/05/2015  6.47
19/05/2015  0
20/05/2015  0
21/05/2015  4.97
22/05/2015  0
25/05/2015  0
26/05/2015  0
27/05/2015  19.28
28/05/2015  4.580833333
```

Comment: Can you create data sample?

Comment: there's a built in `mean()` function on pandas dataframe, if that helps. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Comment: @jezrael: done see above. Ivan, I am using mean()

Comment: Thank you, can you create expected output from sample data?

Comment: @jezrael, done. thanks for looking into it

Comment: @Tikhon - Can you test `u.iloc[period-1] = u.iloc[:period].mean()` ? There is only 13 rows of data, so for me `period = 14` for sample data not working (tested with period = 13 with sample data)

Comment: @jezrael - This works, Thank you! I'd love to know what I messed up. Please post this as the answer so that I may accept it. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select rows by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and then also is used [`Series.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html) method from pandas:

```
u.iloc[period-1] = u.iloc[:period].mean()
```